# npm install error on Windows 7 wtih EPERM operation not permitted error

Tags: windows, npm, npm-install

First, The other answer recommended here is specific to messing up the prefix in npm config, which I haven't done. So I don't think this is a duplicate of that question.

The specific error is EPERM: operation not permitted, rename '/Users/AppData/Roaming/npm/node-modules/create-react-app' -> '/Users/Appdata/Roaming/npm/node_modules/create-react-app.DELETE'

There are a lot of proposed solutions for this. Top ones appear to be:

Run cmd with Run as Administrator; tried this, didn't work.
clear the npm cache; tried this, didn't work. In fact, this command produced the same error. I didn't find any npm cache file in the APPDATA directory either.

I also tried running this via running the node.js command prompt as Admin. Same error.

Another suggestion is to turn off anti-virus, but that is not an option for me because this is a work/corporate provisioned PC running Windows 7.

I'm running node v6.11 and npm v 3.10.10

Any other suggestions?